# i want to store strings in to storage so that when ever i reopen the app the strings should be there to be edited

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want the two user input strings i.e (ip and port) to be saved to storage so that once I've entered and hit save button they should be there even after closing and reopening the app

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static String p = "port number";
public static String u = "url/ip ";
public static String Mypreferences = "myprefs";
Activity context;
EditText iptxt,porttxt;
Button save;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

u/Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
iptxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txturl);
porttxt=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtport);
save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn1);
sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Mypreferences,context.MODE_PRIVATE);
save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
u/Override
public void onClick (View v ) {
String ip = iptxt.getText().toString();
String port = porttxt.getText().toString();
String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
MqttAndroidClient client =
new MqttAndroidClient(context.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://"+ip +port,
clientId);
try {
IMqttToken token = client.connect();
token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
u/Override
public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
// We are connected
//Log.d(TAG, "onSuccess");
}

u/Override
public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
// Something went wrong e.g. connection timeout or firewall problems
//Log.d(TAG, "onFailure");
}
});
} catch (MqttException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putString(p,port);
editor.putString(u,ip);
editor.commit();
ip = sharedPreferences.getString(u,"defaul if empty");
port = sharedPreferences.getString(p,"dfault ");
}

});
}

}
```

Comment: can you explain what happens with the code you have provided?

Comment: sorry ill tr to format the code

Comment: @rbd_sqrl this code is for an android application which should be mqtt client for smart home devices, ip is where the user should input their ip address and port is for entering port number you can see them in code as {"tcp://"+ip +port}